A definite integral of a hypergeometric series related to the enumeration of fusenes
If my calculations are correct, the number of (not necessarily planar) fusenes of perimeter $2n$ grows asymptotically like $\mu^n$ where
\begin{equation}
\mu = \frac{6}{\int_0^{1/6} H(t)\mathrm{d}t} = 3.5460\ldots,
\end{equation}
and $H(t)$ is the hypergeometric series with radius of convergence $1/6$ given by
\begin{equation}
H(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(3k)!}{(k!)^3} (1+2t)^{k}t^{2k-2} = \frac{_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;27t^2(1+2t)\right)-1}{t^2}.
\end{equation}
Alternatively $H(t)$ can be expressed in terms of a complete elliptic integral.
I am curious to know: does $\mu$ admit a more explicit expression in terms of known constants?
Self-avoiding polygons of perimeter $2n$ on the honeycomb lattice form a strict subclass of fusenes. The number of these polygons is famously known, since the prediction by Nienhuis and the proof by Duminil-Copin and Smirnov, to grow with slightly lower rate $\mu_{SAP} = 2+\sqrt{2} = 3.4142\ldots$.
So it is natural to ask: is there an easy way (beyond numeric evaluation) to confirm from the formula above that $\mu > \mu_{SAP}$?

The integral you wrote down evaluates to
$$ I \, = \, \int_0^{1/6} H(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \, = \, 5 - \frac{6\sqrt{3}}{\pi} \, .$$
You can derive this result by expressing the integral as an integral of a modular form and below I give a brief summary of the computation.
First we substitute $t = \frac{h}{1+6 \, h}$ with the Hauptmodul $h$ of $\Gamma_0(6)$ given by
$$ h(\tau) \, = \, \frac{\eta(2\tau) \, \eta(6\tau)^5}{\eta(\tau)^5 \, \eta(3\tau)} \, , $$
where $\eta$ denotes the Dedekind eta function. The map $\tau \mapsto t(\tau)$ gives a bijection between $i \, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $(0,1/6]$. Pulling back one obtains
$$ I \, = \, \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( -2\pi i \int_0^{t^{-1}(\epsilon)} f(\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau + \left(6-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)\right) \, ,$$
with
$$ f(\tau) \, = \, \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;27\, t(\tau)^2(1+2\, t(\tau))\right)}{t(\tau)^2} t'(\tau) \, . $$
Now we can use that $f$ is a modular form of weight $3$ under $\Gamma_0(6)$ (and with the non-trivial Dirichlet character of modulus 6). Even stronger, $f$ is the second derivative of a modular form of weight $-1$. More concretely, we have
$$ f \, = \, \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2} g'' $$
with
$$ g(\tau) \, = \, \frac{1}{t(\tau) \, {_2F_1}\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;27\, t(\tau)^2(1+2\, t(\tau))\right)} \, . $$
This allows us to simplify the integral to
$$ I \, = \, \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( -\frac{1}{2\pi i}g'(t^{-1}(\epsilon))+\left( 6-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) \right) + \frac{1}{2\pi i}g'(0)$$
and it only remains to expand around the cusps $0$ and $\infty$. In terms of $q = e^{2\pi i \, \tau}$ we have
\begin{align*} 
t(\tau) \, &= \, q - q^2 + O(q^3) \\
g(\tau) \, &= \, q^{-1} + O(1) \\
g(-1/6\tau) \, &= \, \frac{1}{6\tau} \, \left(12\sqrt{-3}+O(q)\right)
\end{align*}
for $\tau \rightarrow \infty$ and the result follows.

Great, that is about as simple an expression as one could have hoped for! Do you have a reference or explanation for the statement that $f$ is a modular form of weight 3 under $\Gamma_0(6)$? My modular forms are a bit rusty... This settles the second question as well, provided we admit that $\pi < \frac{6}{17}\sqrt{3}(1+3\sqrt{2})$.

There are many ways to prove that $f$ is modular. A good starting point is the family of elliptic curves $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3-3,\psi,x_1,x_1,x_3=0$. One period  is $2\pi i , {_2F_1}\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;z)\right)$ with $z = 1/\psi^3$ and the monodromy group is $\Gamma_1(3)$. Taking a suitable quotient of periods you obtain a bijection $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{H}}/\Gamma_0(3)$. The inverse is a Hauptmodul $\tau\mapsto z(\tau)$ of $\Gamma_0(3)$ and it follows that $\tau\mapsto {_2F_1}\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;z(\tau))\right)$ is a modular form of weight 1 under $\Gamma_1(3)$.

I forgot to remark that you can express the equation $f , = , \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2} g''$ also as $\frac{F(t)}{t^2} , \mathrm{d}t , = , -\mathrm{d}\left( \frac{(1+2 , t) , (1+3 , t) , (1-6 , t)}{t} , (F(t)+t , F'(t))\right)$, where $F(t) , = , _2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;27 , t^2 , (1+2 , t))\right)$. Then you can get around the use of modular forms.

I see, so we can integrate simply using the hypergeometric differential equation. (Do you by any chance have an idea how to deal with the integral of $F(t)/t \mathrm{d}t$?)

The form $\frac{F(t)}{t} , \mathrm{d}t$ is not exact but its integrals can be expressed as integrals of Eisenstein series. What numbers you will get depend on the precise form of the integral (won't be too complicated). I am happy to explain this in more detail, but the comments here might be the wrong place for that.
